# Remove __MACOSX directory in zip files by using shell

Tags: bash, zip

I want to remove __MACOSX directory in zip files that are made by Mac.

With `zip foo.zip -qd "__MACOSX/*"` works well.

Then I wrote like following.
`for file in "*.zip"; do zip $file -qd "__MACOSX/*"; done`

But this script have effect only first zip file in the directory.

Next I try to use "find" and "xargs". But it didn't worked at all.
`find . -name "*.zip" -print0 | xargs -0 zip -qd "__MACOSX/*"`

How can I write a script that removes all __MACOSX directory in multiple zip files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to quote the `$file` in the command, but *not* the glob in the `for`:

```
for file in *.zip; do zip "$file" -qd "__MACOSX/*"; done
```